# Python Pandas - Filter by multiple column names

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I apologize, I looked through many other StackOverflow threads and did not find one that was what I'm looking for.

I am trying to use pandas to solve this but I don't necessarily need a pandas solution. I have created a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Provider' : ['Prov1', 'Prov1', 'Prov1', 'Prov1', 'Prov2', 'Prov2', 'Prov2'],
               'Field' : ['Chemistry', 'Biology', 'Chemistry', 'Biology', 'Biology', 'Engineering', 'Biology'],
               'Downloads' : [10, 12, 10, 8, 4, 20, 14]})
```

What I want to do is basically filter by multiple columns. The pseudo code for this would be:

```
#if provider = 'Prov1':
    #for field in provider:
        #sum downloads for these criteria
```

Ideally my output would be a tuple, something like `(Chemistry, 20), (Biology, 20)`.

I've tried various methods using pandas.loc, pandas.groupby but these all seem to allow one level of filtering. Meaning, I can choose one column to filter by. But I don't know how to filter by multiple levels.

Comment: Did you try `df.groupby(['Provider', 'Field'], as_index=False).sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter by `df[df['Provider']=='Prov1']` followed by `groupby` and `sum`:

```
result = df[df['Provider']=='Prov1'].groupby('Field', as_index=False).sum().values.tolist()
```

The result is list of lists:

```
[['Biology', 20], ['Chemistry', 20]]
```